# How do I extract the keys of a dictionary based on a conditional?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am asked to extract the dates of dictionary in which the values exceed the input threshold.

See code beneath:

```
def get_dates(prices,threshold):
    {k:v for  k,v  in prices  if threshold>130}
    

prc = [
    { 'price': 1279.79, 'date': '2020-01-01' },
    { 'price': 139.01, 'date': '2020-01-02' },
    { 'price': 134.3, 'date': '2020-01-03' },
    { 'price': 120.99, 'date': '2020-01-04' }
]

get_dates(prc, 130.0)
```

Ideally,  the function should return the respective date on which the price is beyond the threshold (130). My code does not however return anything.

Comment: the function returns `None`... pass the list of dictionaries to the function (as argument), make a for loop and check the condition. Store the results in a list and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return the dates you want, use a list comprehension that gets the `date` key from each dict where `price` is above `threshold`:

```
def get_dates(prices,threshold):
    return [d['date'] for d in prices if d['price'] > threshold]

prc = [
    { 'price': 1279.79, 'date': '2020-01-01' },
    { 'price': 139.01, 'date': '2020-01-02' },
    { 'price': 134.3, 'date': '2020-01-03' },
    { 'price': 120.99, 'date': '2020-01-04' }
]

print(get_dates(prc, 130.0))  # ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`list comprehensions`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/) and return `dict`s if the price is larger than the threshold.

*[Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)*

```
# we use 'dict.get' with default value '0' for price if don't exists.
def get_dates(prices,threshold):
    return [dct['date'] for dct in prices if dct.get('price', 0) > threshold]
            

prc = [
    { 'price': 1279.79, 'date': '2020-01-01' },
    { 'price': 139.01, 'date': '2020-01-02' },
    { 'price': 134.3, 'date': '2020-01-03' },
    { 'price': 120.99, 'date': '2020-01-04' }
]

get_dates(prc, 130.0)
```

Output:

```
['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03']
```

Comment: Your solution worked! Thank you. What, if I only want to extract the key "date" alone?

Comment: @Kash, you're welcome, the answer updated ;)

Comment: The 0 after "price" was not necessary btw to execute the same output.

Comment: @Kash, test with this : `prc = [
    { 'price': 134.3, 'date': '2020-01-03' },
    { 'date': '2020-01-04' }    
]` if you don't use `get` you get an error.

Comment: @Kash, we use `dict.get()` for the condition if the key doesn't exist in `dict` and we don't get any error if the key doesn't exist and returns the default value then the code run correctly always.

Comment: Not raising an exception isn't the same thing as running "correctly".  If the expectation is that the input should always have a `price` key, the *correct* thing is arguably to immediately raise an error if that's not the case, in order to make debugging easier.  Using the `[]` operator gets you that for free.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no return keyword in your function.
Then do it like this

```
def get_dates(prices, threshold) :
    dates=[]
    for dict in prices:
        if dict['price']>threshold:
            dates.append(dict['date'])
    return dates
```

This will return an array of dates
Then to get this array use
`dates=get_dates(prc, 130)`